# al sending fake keyboard events, whitespace issues

Tags: c, linux, gtk, xlib

I'm creating a program using gtk and xlib(xtst) to send fake keypresses to an application, I have created this loop to send the keypresses to the active window:

```
Display *dis;
        dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        KeyCode modcode = 0; //init value
        int i;
        char hello[]="hello world";
        char temp[1];
        int size=sizeof(hello);
        sleep(2);
        for (i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
                temp[0]=hello[i];
                temp[1]='\0';     //string terminator
                g_print("%s\n",temp);  //works fine, whitespace is printed
                modcode = XKeysymToKeycode(dis, XStringToKeysym(temp));
                XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, modcode, False, 0);
                XFlush(dis);
        //      sleep(1);
                XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, modcode, True, 0);
                XFlush(dis);
                XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, modcode, False, 0);
                XFlush(dis);
}
```

problem is it prints 'helloworld' instead, it is incapable of dealing with whitespace or any special characters

thanks

Comment: `temp[1]='\0'` is undefined behaviour. `temp` has only one cell, `temp[0]`. You have out-of-bounds access.

Comment: I've increased the array size to 2, still getting the same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created my own translation function as you had suggested:

```
switch (hello[i])
{
case ' ':
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 65, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 65, False, 0);
```

as for capital letters, I used a shift key with the regular key:

```
case 'T':
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 50, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 28, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 28, False, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 50, False, 0);
break;
```

and special characters:

```
case '\n':
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 36, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 36, False, 0);
break;
```

things are working fine now, thanks Ishay

Answer (score 0):

```
Display *dis;
        dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        KeyCode modcode = 0; //init value
        int i;
        char hello[]="hello world";
        char temp[2]; //Size is 2!!!
        int size=sizeof(hello);
        sleep(2);
        for (i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
                temp[0]=hello[i];
                temp[1]='\0';     //string terminator
                g_print("%s\n",temp);  //works fine, whitespace is printed
                if (temp[0] == ' ')
                    modcode = XK_KP_Space
                else
                    modcode = XKeysymToKeycode(dis, XStringToKeysym(temp));
                XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, modcode, False, 0);
                XFlush(dis);
        //      sleep(1);
                XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, modcode, True, 0);
                XFlush(dis);
                XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, modcode, False, 0);
                XFlush(dis);
}
```

You're storing 2 values into a single value array. Change temp[1] to temp[2] (as in the example).

Comment: Okay, 2 points - 1. why are you calling XTestFakeKeyEvent three times? It should send the keycode right after XFlush. 2. Can you print the modcode generated by XKeysymToKeycode for the white spaces?

Comment: You are right I definitely did not need all those flushes, and I was able to remove one Xtestfake..., I need 2 however, one for  a key press and the other for the key release 
otherwise, strings are not printed correctly

How can i print the modecode?

Comment: Well, a keycode is just a number between 8-255 as far as I can recall. Try using straight printf. If that doesn't work, look into the definition of KeyCode and comment here with the fields

Comment: ok here's what I got:
43 26 46 46 32 204 25 32 27 46 40 204
h   e   l     l    o    ' '    w  o   r    l    d

the terminator and whitespace have the same value, is that normal?

Comment: I also tried some special chars like ! and % and I get 204 where these characters should be

Comment: That's odd, and probably the reason you don't see space. Try using tab instead and postthe keycodes again

Comment: tried tab as part of the string and \t, both yied 204

Comment: Okay, I looked up the 204 keycode (http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/keysymdef.h) and it seems it isn't a terminator after all, but IGrave. It's very odd that XStringToKeysym returns this value for space, but you can fix it - test for a space, and if found, use XK_KP_Space as the keycode. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: that sounds reasonable, but what about the other special characters? :(

Comment: I don't have the X11 code, but if you do and you want a general solution, you can check the translation function XKeysymToKeycode to understand why you get these strange translations. One last thing - are you using an English keyboard and locale?

Comment: english keyboard yes, locale:
adel@b5400 ~ $ locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX

I'll check out the function try to figure things out

Comment: tried creating my own converting function:
KeyCode keysymtokeycode(char key)
{
switch(key)
{
case 'a':
return 0x0061;
break;
default: 
return 0xff80;
break;
}
}
not yielding the results I was looking for, I got the values from keysymdef.h